# Black backround after render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, texturing

I am a begginer in blender and I download the [template from this link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QrQeF0IyQYQ). If I am render the image i [get this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dt15nmxo7lrpbd6/untitled.png?dl=0). It have got black backround!!! 
Please help!
Thanks!

Comment: do you want to know how to get a different background?

Comment: No. How to render with planet and backround, because I get this: https://www.dropbox.com/s/dt15nmxo7lrpbd6/untitled.png?dl=0

Comment: so your problem is that the planet is not rendering. Is the planet visible in the 3D viewport?

Comment: Yes! This is my problem :-(

Comment: [is this your problem?](http://i.stack.imgur.com/HWjqZ.png)

Comment: no. Here is my screen shot https://www.dropbox.com/s/4mwkyq4jtcmu9pi/Screenshot%202016-01-20%2015.59.21.png?dl=0

Comment: I think you need to check those toggle buttons in the scene settings. The only one you have checked is 'universal' check the others: 'night' 'shadow' 'atmosphere' 'sun

Comment: Not work. Some render...